# Efficient sorted bounding box query

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing, gis

How would I create indexes in PostgresSQL 8.3 which would make a sorted bounding box query efficient? The table I'm querying has quite a few rows.

That is I want the create indexes that makes the following query as efficient as possible:

```
SELECT * FROM features 
WHERE lat BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND lng BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The features table look like this:

```
   Column   |          Type          |   
------------+------------------------+
 id         | integer                |
 name       | character varying(255) | 
 type       | character varying(255) | 
 lat        | double precision       | 
 lng        | double precision       | 
 score      | double precision       | 
 html       | text                   |
```

Answer (score 1):

> To create a GiST index on a point attribute so that we can efficiently use box operators on the result of the conversion function:

```
CREATE INDEX pointloc
    ON points USING gist (box(location,location));
SELECT * FROM points
    WHERE box(location,location) && '(0,0),(1,1)'::box;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createindex.html

This is the example in 9.0 docs. It should work for 8.3 though as these are features that have been around for ages.

Comment: Can I also get this to efficiently order the result by the score column? Specifically some queries will return results that are tens of thousands rows large. I want to only use the top (say) 100 of those sorted by score.

Comment: if you do `order by score desc limit 100` then postgres will use a top-N heapsort to maintain the top 100 results in memory (assuming your work_mem is large enough) rather than doing a full sort and just reading off the top 100.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [GiST index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-indexes.html) to implement an R-Tree. This type of index is poorly documented, so you might have to trawl through example code in the source distribution.

(Note: My prior advice to use R-Tree indexes appears to be out of date; they are deprecated.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd want to take a look at [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/), a PostgreSQL module for spatial data types and queries. It supports quick lookups using GiST indexes. Unfortunately I can't guide you further as I haven't used PostGIS myself.

Comment: Is PostGIS part of a default PostgreSQL installation or do you need to set it up separately? In particular, would something like Heroku have it pre-installed?

Comment: Apparently it is available on dedicated Heroku instances but they are quite expensive. I don't really need anything fancy so it would be nice if this is possible to do in PostgreSQL without PostGIS.

Comment: You can setup PostGIS yourself if you can compile code on your machine (or use the provided dist packes - it's easier)