# Select rows with latitude-longitude values inside 10km radius?

Tags: mysql

I have a site which shows posts from a certain city. I was thinking of changing from Cities to a radius around the user's location (10km in this case).

I don't know how to query using a radius. I can only think of doing a query with two conditions and get a square. e.g:

```
SELECT fields
FROM points
WHERE lat BETWEEN LAT1 AND LAT2
AND lon BETWEEN LON1 AND LON2
```

Is it possible to select rows inside a radius of X km/mi from a certain location?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492750/efficient-sorted-bounding-box-query) question might be of value to you - not MySQL but the idea still holds.

Comment: Do you have a formula to compute the distance between two points?  That would help in determining if it can be done in SQL.

Comment: I think it's 111km per latitude or longitude point aprox. So using pythagoras the function would be `(lat*111)^2+(lon*111)^2=distance^2`. I'm not sure how to `CREATE FUNCTION` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use a `WHERE` query on any condition. So, supposing you have a function `distance()` that can compute the distance between two geographic points, you could do:

```
SELECT fields
FROM points
WHERE distance(lat, lon, city_lat, city_lon) <= 10
```

where `city_lat` and `city_lon` is the location of the city centre.

PostgreSQL contains a add-on function called [`earthdistance()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/earthdistance.html) that would help.

Comment: that sounds feasible. Just a question about the function. I just write it above the query like a normal PHP function and that would be it? Or do I have to do something different to make it run with the query? I'll accept in a minute

Comment: No, the function would need to be accessible by your database (functions in your PHP script are not), which means you would need to use [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html) in order to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->select('id','name','phone','latitude','longitude')
        ->SQRT("POW(69.1 * (latitude - 24.900110), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (67.099760 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance")
        ->having("distance < 25")
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->get();
```